# BLTouch error on pronterface, nothing connected to the board

Tags: troubleshooting, 3dtouch

This is a brand new Two Trees Bluer Plus 3D printer. Default, it has a 3DTouch probe installed.

[image]

Printer is broken now, I couldn't use it even for a week...

In middle of a long print, our home fuse blew. I am not sure because of the printer or not. I open the fuse and printer cant start. It was stuck at restart cycle and keeps restarting. I cut the power and check for stepper drivers. They look fine. Install them again and restart the printer. Then magic smoke appeared and all drivers are dead. But printer can reach menus.
First I buy new drivers and looking for if the board is salvageable or not.

When I installed new drivers, the printer would start up, but no movement of the 3DTouch probe at startup. Its blue and red lights are constantly on.

I can manually move X, Z and E, but Y moved a little after that it became unresponsive (I tried to swap drivers, but always Y seems problematic, the drivers looks fine) .

The 3DTouch probe is not working so it can't home Z. Y cannot be homed either but I can home the X-axis. Bed and nozzle look okay; they heat up correctly. There was no error message on the printer screen. Two trees uses a custom Repetier version. This is Pronterface's error message:

```
Connecting...
MKS Robin Nano 1.0.0
echo: Last Updated: 2017-12-25 12:00 | Author: (none, default config)
echo:Compiled: Jan  8 2021
echo: Free Memory: 4396  PlannerBufferBytes: 1344
echo:V47 stored settings retrieved (1140 bytes; crc 10556)
echo:  G21    ; Units in mm
echo:Filament settings: Disabled
echo:  M200 D3.00
echo:  M200 T1 D3.00
echo:  M200 D0
echo:Steps per unit:
echo:  M92 X160.00 Y160.00 Z800.00
echo:  M92 T0 E430.00
  M92 T1 E800.00
echo:Maximum feedrates (units/s):
echo:  M203 X100.00 Y100.00 Z4.00
echo:  M203 T0 E70.00
  M203 T1 E70.00
echo:Maximum Acceleration (units/s2):
echo:  M201 X500 Y500 Z100
echo:  M201 T0 E1000
  M201 T1 E1000
echo:Acceleration (units/s2): P<print_accel> R<retract_accel> T<travel_accel>
echo:  M204 P500.00 R500.00 T1000.00
echo:Advanced: S<min_feedrate> T<min_travel_feedrate> B<min_segment_time_us> X<max_xy_jerk> Z<max_z_jerk> E<max_e_jerk>
echo:  M205 S0.00 T0.00 B20000 X10.00 Y10.00 Z0.40 E5.00
echo:Home offset:
echo:  M206 X0.00 Y0.00 Z0.00
echo:Hotend offsets:
echo:  M218 T1 X-20.00 Y-5.00
echo:  M420 S0
echo:Endstop adjustment:
echo:  M666
echo:PID settings:
echo:  M301 P22.20 I1.08 D114.00
echo:Z-Probe Offset (mm):
echo:  M851 Z-2.80
Error:STOP called because of BLTouch error - restart with M999
Error:Printer stopped due to errors. Fix the error and use M999 to restart. (Temperature is reset. Set it after restarting)
```

Comment: This sounds like a lot of problems which I wouldn't start to troubleshoot, basically there are issues with Y and the 3DTouch. You could check the 3DTouch wiring, but that doesn't fix the Y problem. I'd replace the board and buy a real BLTouch. There might be things broken beyond fixing. What makes it difficult that this printer also has a custom screen with its own firmware, it might be difficult for someone without much experience to solve this.

Comment: Thank you for the reply @0scar. I don't have much hope for the board as you mention. Can I ask you some rookie question? I feel like drivers and cpu heats up so quickly when i start to move axises. Cpu heats up even on idle 70 80 degree Celsius if i guess. Hard to touch. Drivers are tmc2209 by the way. Not sure what mode. I examine drivers they were heat up before printer broke never check cpu before incident. Do you think these are normal?

Comment: I believe the max temperature of the TMC2209 is 125 ºC. The printer uses the MKS Robin Nano board V1.2.